# Setting the mime type

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to write an excel and send it to the user as a response in an application using Play `framework 1.x`. But I am not sure how to set the response `content-type/MIME-type` for returning doc or excel file.

Let me know the steps for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#result):

> To serve binary data, such as a file stored on the server, use the renderBinary method. For example, if you have a User model with a play.db.jpa.Blob photo property, add a controller method to load the model object and render the image with the stored MIME type:

```
public static void userPhoto(long id) { 
    final User user = User.findById(id); 
    response.setContentTypeIfNotSet(user.photo.type());
    java.io.InputStream binaryData = user.photo.get();
    renderBinary(binaryData);
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response. I don't have any model with a property set for the response type, I need to add it in the response explictily. Any pointers for this?

Comment: instead of `response.setContentTypeIfNotSet(user.photo.type())`, do `response.setContentTypeIfNotSet("application/vnd.ms-excel")` (or whatever mime type you want). http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.5/play/mvc/Http.Response.html#setContentTypeIfNotSet%28java.lang.String%29